# Why my WCF Service won't return the value to the client?

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I having a problem, when i create a WCF Service, i test it with wcftestclient.exe, yes it return a value just like i want it

but when in the winform, it just got blank, here is my code

here is my datacontract class (dcClient.vb)

```
Public Class dcClient
Private _userName As String
Private _password As String
Private _userLevel As String
Private _userStatus As String

Public Property userName As String
    Get
        Return _userName
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _userName = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property password As String
    Get
        Return _password
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _password = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property userLevel As String
    Get
        Return _userLevel
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _userLevel = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property userStatus As String
    Get
        Return _userStatus
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _userStatus = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

Here is my ServiceClient.vb

> ```
> Public Function loginClient(ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As String) As dcClient Implements IServiceClient.loginClient
>     Dim dcClients As New dcClient
>     Dim conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBCS").ConnectionString
>     Using con As New SqlConnection(conString)
>         Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("spSelectMasterUser", con)
>         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
> ```

```
        Dim parameteruserName As New SqlParameter
        parameteruserName.ParameterName = "@userName"
        parameteruserName.Value = userName
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameteruserName)

        Dim parameterPassword As New SqlParameter
        parameterPassword.ParameterName = "@password"
        parameterPassword.Value = password
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterPassword)

        con.Open()

        Dim dtReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dtReader.Read
            dcClients.userName = dtReader("userName").ToString
            dcClients.password = dtReader("password").ToString
            dcClients.userLevel = dtReader("userLevel").ToString
            dcClients.userStatus = dtReader("userStatus").ToString
        End While

    End Using

    Return dcClients
End Function
```

Up there is my service code, below is my client code

> ```
> Private Sub btn_login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_login.Click
>     Dim I_Sc As New Service_Ref.ServiceClientClient
>     Dim dcClient As New Service_Ref.dcClient
>     Try
>         dcClient = I_Sc.loginClient("kevin", "kevin")
>     Catch ex As Exception
>         MessageBox.Show("Login Failed")
>     End Try
>
>
>     Dim username As String = dcClient.userName
>     Dim userlevel As String = dcClient.userLevel
>     Dim userstatus As String = dcClient.userStatus
>
>     Label4.Text = username
>     Label5.Text = userlevel
>     Label6.Text = userstatus
>
>
> End Sub
> ```

in wcftestclient, when i input "kevin","kevin" (that's what my database record is), i return the entire value that i needed. But when i execute the button in the client, it returned blank, nothing.. what i miss here?

Comment: yep, it show nothing that returned from the property

Comment: And did you set a breakpoint to where you think the property was properly written? *Debug it*!

Comment: yeah.. i set all of it, and i see the value is "nothing"